# Python simple loop EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, eol

I am trying to write out line by line of a text file however I keep getting the following error:

File "E:\Print\test.py", line 8
print "(lines)
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

```
myfile = open('log.txt', 'r')
count =  0
while 1:
    lines = myfile.readline()
    if not(lines):
        break
    count = count + 1
    print "(lines)
myfile.close()
```

any help appreciated

Comment: `print "(lines)` notice something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close your double quotes after you opened them, or maybe you put one by accident:

```
print "(lines)
```

Here is your edited code:

```
myfile = open('log.txt', 'r')
count =  0
while 1:
    lines = myfile.readline()
    if not(lines):
        break
    count = count + 1
    print(lines)
myfile.close()
```

A `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` basically means that it was looking for another quote to end the string, but it came to the ***E*nd *O*f the *L*ine** (hence **EOL**), and it didn't find anything.